# c++ compiler error when using a generic class having struct member

Tags: c++, class, generics, struct, tree

I'm constructing a generic binary tree which includes a struct, TreeNode. I implement a function rootPtr() which returns the pointer to the root of the tree. *binarytree.h* is simply the following:

```
template <class T>
class BinaryTree {
public:

typedef struct TreeNode {
    T item;
    TreeNode *leftChildPtr; // pointer to left child
    TreeNode *rightChildPtr;

public:
    TreeNode(const T& nodeItem,
            TreeNode *left,
            TreeNode * right)
    : item(nodeItem), leftChildPtr(left), rightChildPtr(right) {
    }

    TreeNode(const T & nodeItem)
    : item(nodeItem) {
        leftChildPtr = NULL;
        rightChildPtr = NULL;
    }
  } TN; //end treenode

//Function prototype
TN* rootPtr() const;

private:
    TN *root;

} //end binarytree
```

This is the snippet from *binarytree.cpp* which results error.

```
template <class T>
BinaryTree<T>::TN* BinaryTree<T>::rootPtr() {
    return root;
}
```

Compiler complains **error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token** 
I've seen this error before and handled it by using like `BinaryTree::` but this time since it's generic, I don't know what should I do. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplified rule of thumb: you cannot define member functions when the class has a template in a separate cpp file. Try putting that together with the class definition, on the header ;)

Comment: I accept yours as answer but as you know it's workaround. I still wonder how can I do it in the format above.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `typename` before the return type in the function definition, since `TN` is a member of a dependent class.

Comment: adding `typename` gives another error:  **expected nested-name-specifier before "TN"** and **ISO C++ forbids declaration of `TN' with no type**

Comment: Are you `#include`ing the header file in the source file?